# Shapeless + ScalaZ: Keeping track of the return type inside an applicative builder

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless

A question for @TravisBrown mostly, based on his previous blog post [**here**](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/05/applicative-validation-syntax/).

For reasons to do with a legacy codebase which pain my heart to greatly to outline here, I am required to label validations with a string key when building the applicative chains. In hope that I am not overcomplicating things, I've adapted the blog post version to Shapeless 2, but failing miserably at isolating the bit I need simply for the chain.

I believe the underlying trick is to simply repeatedly use the first `ApplicativeBuilder` in the chain, and then unwrapping the result, going from `(D, (C, (B, A))) => (A, B, C, D)` by unwrapping one nesting at a time.

How do I reuse that to do the following:

```
    package test {
      type ErrorsOr[A] = ValidationNel[String, A]
      type NestedErrorsOr[T] = ValidationNel[(String, String), T]
      type Validator[A] = String => ErrorsOr[A]

      implicit class VdNelAug[T](val vd: ErrorsOr[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def label(key: String): WrappedValidation[T] = new WrappedValidation[T](key, vd.leftMap(
          nel => nel.map(value => key -> value))
        )
      }
    }



class WrappedValidation[T](val prop: String, val validation: NestedErrorsOr[T]) {

    def and[A](wv: WrappedValidation[A]): ValidationBuilder[
      NestedErrorsOr[T] :: NestedErrorsOr[A] :: HNil,
      T :: A :: HNil] = {

      // I don't know how to infer the type here.
      new ValidationBuilder(
        List(wv.prop, prop),
        validation |@| wv.validation)
      )
    }
  }
class ValidationBuilder[
  ValTypes <: HList,
  ArgTypes <: HList,
  BuilderType = ???
](builder: BuilderType?): {

def apply[V, Ret, Rev <: Hlist, Args <: HList](fn: V => Ret)(
   implicit rev: Reverse.Aux[ArgTypes, Rev]
     tupler: Tupler.Aux[Rev, Args],
     ev: Args =:= V
): Either[CustomError, Ret] = {
   // ingnore the custom conversion of the nel, this is just about
   // performing a simple groupBy the label such as all the error messages
   // For a given label are returned under the same key.
   builder.fold(nel => nel.toCustom, fn)
}
```

I believe I get the principle but the gap comes from the lack of Shapeless API experience.

```
object Applier extends Poly2 {
    implicit def ap[F[_]: Applicative, H, T <: HList, R]:
    Case2.Aux[Applier.type, F[(H :: T) => R], F[H], F[T => R]] =
      at[F[(H :: T) => R], F[H]](
        (f, fa) => fa <*> f.map(hf => (h: H) => (t: T) => hf(h :: t))
      )
  }
```

I'm guess the trick is the combo of the poly and the folder in the example but I don't understand why the provided `F[_]` is necessary, given we can predict the type of the apply by using the hlist chain we can create from the type params of the validations themselves. By `F[_]` I don't mean the one in the `Poly`, but the one used in deriving the correct validation.

Couldn't that function just be an arbitrary `In => Out` where the `In` is the same as the type of the unwrapped validation?